# Minikub Not Starting Ubuntu 18.4

Tags: kubernetes

Minikube not starting with several error messages. 
kubectl version gives following message with port related message:

```
iqbal@ThinkPad:~$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"12", GitVersion:"v1.12.2", GitCommit:"17c77c7898218073f14c8d573582e8d2313dc740", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-10-24T06:54:59Z", GoVersion:"go1.10.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

Comment: Did you try `minikube start --vm-driver=none`? Also, what is your docker version `docker version`?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't give more details, but there are some concerns that I solved few days ago about minikube issues with kubernetes **1.12**.

Indeed, the compatibility matrix between kubernetes and docker  recommends to run : 
Docker **18.06** + kubernetes **1.12** (Docker 18.09 is not supported now).

Thus, make sure `docker version` is NOT above **18.06**. Then, run the following:

```
# clean up
minikube delete

minikube start --vm-driver="none"
kubectl get nodes
```

If you are still encountering issues, please give more details, namely `minikube logs`.

Comment: Thank you so much for trying to help.  However, i am using virtualbox and not docker.  Please see if you can help there.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the VM driver add the appropriate `--vm-driver=xxx` flag to `minikube start`. Minikube supports
the following drivers:

- virtualbox
- vmwarefusion
- [KVM2](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/blob/master/docs/drivers.md#kvm2-driver)
- [KVM (deprecated in favor of KVM2)](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/blob/master/docs/drivers.md#kvm-driver)
- [hyperkit](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/blob/master/docs/drivers.md#hyperkit-driver)
- [xhyve](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/blob/master/docs/drivers.md#xhyve-driver)
- [hyperv](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/blob/master/docs/drivers.md#hyperV-driver)
- none (**Linux-only**) - this driver can be used to run the Kubernetes cluster components on the host instead of in a VM. This can be useful for CI workloads which do not support nested virtualization. For example, if your vm is virtualbox then use:

  ```
  $ minikube delete
  $ minikube start --vm-driver=virtualbox
  ```